# Specifying Repository for Driver Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, apt

Summary: I am trying to install the xf86-video-fbdev driver (https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xf86-video-fbdev/) on Ubuntu 20.04 using `sudo apt-get install xf86-video-fbdev` as suggested by this (https://opensource.com/article/18/11/how-install-device-driver-linux) article. Unfortunately, I am getting an error: `E: Unable to locate package xf86-video-fbdev`. I suppose this is because I am not specifying a repository in which to look for this package. The command to add the repository in the above article contains a parameter `REPOLIST_OF_DRIVER`, for which I do not know what to use. How can I find what to use for this parameter?

More background: I have a Mid 2010 21.5" iMac on which I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 (single boot). According to the ArchWiki page, this particular model has some issues with linux which I was not aware of when I first started trying this install (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMac_(21.5-inch,_Mid_2010)). So, I am trying to follow the instructions at this ArchWiki link to install the xf86-video-fbdev and xorg-xrandr drivers and then write the specified script. As laid out above, I am running into issues with installing these drivers.

I would highly appreciate clear and detailed suggestions, since I am not very adept at understanding computers. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xf86-video-fbdev is an Xorg driver for framebuffer devices. There is no official xf86-video-fbdev package available for Ubuntu 20.04 and no PPA that contains the xf86-video-fbdev package, but there is xf86-video-fbdev source code at [GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-fbdev) and [xf86-video-fbdev](https://software.opensuse.org/package/xf86-video-fbdev) is in the official openSUSE repositories.

[xserver-xorg-video-fbdev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xserver-xorg-video-fbdev) provides the driver for the Linux framebuffer device (aka 'fbdev'). To install this graphics driver on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
sudo reboot
```